# How to add Named Check Constraint while defining the Column during Table creation in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, create-table, check-constraints

I have the following CREATE table query:

```
-- Create table
CREATE TABLE USER2 (
--  Column definitions
    OID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIME TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL,
    LAST_MOD_TIME TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR2(500 CHAR) NOT NULL,

--  Other columns

--  Primary key constraint
    CONSTRAINT USER_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (OID),

--  Foreign key constraints

--  List of foreign key constraints

--  Unique key constraints

--  List of unique key constraints

--  Check constraints
    CONSTRAINT USER_OID_NOTNULL_CK
        CHECK (OID IS NOT NULL),
    CONSTRAINT USER_CTM_NOTNULL_CK
        CHECK (CREATION_TIME IS NOT NULL),
    CONSTRAINT USER_LMT_NOTNULL_CK
        CHECK (LAST_MOD_TIME IS NOT NULL),
    CONSTRAINT USER_NME_NOTNULL_CK,

--  List of check constraints
);
```

When it gets executed in Oracle 11g, it creates duplicate Check Constraints; one set contains the Check Constraints that I have specified explicitly and another set contains autogenerated Check Constraints which are generated by the DB itself as I have specified `NOT NULL` in the column definitions.

When I don't specify `NOT NULL` in the column definitions, from SQL Developer, in the table definition view, the columns are shown as `Nullable Yes`.

I want the columns to be shown as `Nullable No` also the Check Constraints will be named. How can I achieve this?

Comment: it is because you cannot create not null constraint table level

Comment: `CREATION_TIME TIMESTAMP (6) constraint SCOPING2_CTM_NOTNULL_CK NOT NULL`?

Comment: when you create a column with primary key you do not have to mention that column as not null and do not have to create a not null constraint again.

Comment: @jarlh, I worked :). Can you please post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it, I also have updated the Check Constraint names as I made typological mistakes. You may want to fix that also in your comment and in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to double the NOT NULL specifications, simply name the NOT NULL constraints when you define the columns, e.g.:

```
...
CREATION_TIME TIMESTAMP (6) constraint SCOPING2_CTM_NOTNULL_CK NOT NULL,
...
```